# How to add wildcard to URL in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.NET and I'm trying to make it so that a wildcard (*) could be replace by any string. something like this:

```
    If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString = "http://google.com/*" Then

        'Insert action here'

    End If
```

Unfortunately that wildcard does not work .I want to have it so that the URL could be anything as long it starts with http://google.com/
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this instead:

```
If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString.StartsWith("http://google.com/") Then

    'Insert action here'

End If
```